# Knockout switch-case plugin is not hiding/showing the correct value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using the [knockout-switch-case extension](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case) plugin, and I am having a difficult time getting it to work with even the simplest of code. Using knockout 3.0, below is the code I'm using; both the *I'm a boolean!* and *I'm an other* text will be shown.

```
// Javascript
ko.applyBindings({type: 'integer'});

<!-- Html bindings -->
<div>
  <!-- ko switch: type -->
  <!-- ko case: 'boolean' -->
  <span> Im a boolean!</span>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko case: $else -->
  <span> Im an other!</span>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5H92/) of the code. Am I doing something incorrect in use of this plugin?

Comment: You haven't included the switch-case plugin in your fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/Nx4DV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the ko-switch plugin is not loaded in your fiddle.

manji solution may not work in some browser (e.g. IE11) because of mime type enforcement: github doesn't return the raw js file with a javascript mime type, which IE refuses to execute with error SEC7112.

Here's a fiddle that works. I've referenced the plugin at rawgithub.com instead (notice there's no dot like in raw.github.com):

```
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case/master/knockout-switchcase.min.js"></script>
<span data-bind='text:type'></span>
<div>
  <!-- ko switch: type -->
  <!-- ko case: 'boolean' -->
  Im a boolean!
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko case: $else -->
  <span> Im an other!</span>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5H92/1/

Tip: to find the error I only had to look at my browser console.

**EDIT**: sorry I pasted the wrong code, but the fiddle was right ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're referencing the github page of the script, not the script file itself.

Correct path: [`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case/master/knockout-switch-case.min.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case/master/knockout-switch-case.min.js).

P.S.: For JSFiddle, `<script>` tag type attribute should be equal to `text/javascript`.

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5H92/2/)

Comment: The `type` attribute defaults to `text/javascript` in HTML5, no need to write it down. Conveniently, even older (non "HTML5") browsers had this behavior.

Comment: Ok, but in JSFiddle if you don't put explicitly 'text/javascript', it will not work.

Comment: That's surely linked to the fact that the URL you use doesn't respond with the javascript mime type (but a raw text instead). I guess your browser picks that up and doesn't execute it. In fact, even with the type IE will refuse to execute it, see my answer. Note that my fiddle doesn't use `type` but still works ;)