# How do I use a switch statement in a binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a ViewModel that looks like:

```
{
    empName: [
        { name: 'NAME1' },
        { name: 'NAME2' }
    ]        
}
```

I want to display different department names according to my `empName` while looping through `name` property using a switch statement.
such that output is:

> Department 1 
>   Department 2

I tried the following:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: empName">
        <div data-bind="switch: name">
        <div data-bind="case: 'Name1'">
            Department 1
        </div>
        <div data-bind="case: 'Name2'">
            Department 2
        </div>

        <div data-bind="case: $default">
        </div>
    </div>
```

But I get the following output:

> Department 1
>   Department 2
>   Department 1
>   Department 2

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I wonder KO has switch-case biding...  So have a look at a library . Hope this helps [Git : knockout-switch-case](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case). Example borrowed from [Switch-Case-Not-Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017862/knockout-switch-case-plugin-is-not-hiding-showing-the-correct-value) is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5H92/1/)

Comment: Put the switch case in the JS. Then just do a foreach on an array of strings in the HTML.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Fully agree. Keep the more lengthy/complex logic out of the bindings. I suggest this in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not rethink the problem a little and move this logic into a function? As a rule of thumb, I try to keep my bindings as simple as possible and put the logic into my javascript.

Here is a full example:

```
var viewModel = {
   empName: [
        { name: 'NAME1' },
        { name: 'NAME2' }
   ]        
};

viewModel.departmentName = function(name) {
    var departmentName = "Department ";

    switch (name) {
        case "NAME2":
            departmentName += "2";
            break;
        case "NAME1":
        default:
            departmentName += "1";
            break;
    }

    return departmentName; 
}.bind(viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

and then in your markup:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: empName">
    <li data-bind="text: viewModel.departmentName(name)"></li>
</ul>
```

which outputs:

> Department 1
>   Department 2

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/42k7gj8f/1/)**

---

On a sidenote, if you really only have two cases (which I assume you don't and you just simplified for this post), then use a ternary operator in the `departmentName` function:

```
return name === "NAME2" ? "Department 2" : "Department 1";
```

Answer (score 4):

My two cents!! Knockout does not have a switch case statement. As suggested by [RP Niemeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11554276/769678)

> Michael Best's switch/case binding
>   (https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case) is quite flexible and
>   can let you easily handle this and more complicated ones (more states
>   than true/false).

Else you could use condition binding as :

```
    <!-- ko if: name == 'NAME1' -->
    <div data-bind="if: name == 'NAME1'">Department 1</div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Also,

```
<div data-bind="if: name == 'NAME1'">Department 1</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yw4bkrzf/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no switch but you can use if:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: empName">
    <div data-bind="if: name == 'Name1'">
        Department 1
    </div>
    <div data-bind="if: name == 'Name2'">
        Department 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. that helps but it creates two extra empty div's. output is as follows  n <div data-bind="foreach: empName">
        <div data-bind="if: name == 'Name1'">
            Department 1
        </div>
        <div data-bind="if: name == 'Name2'"></div>
    
        <div data-bind="if: name == 'Name1'"></div>
        <div data-bind="if: name == 'Name2'">
            Department 2
        </div>
    </div>